# E.apply is not a function when i click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

On framework7 i get the

```
e.apply is not a function
```

error, when i click on a “onclick” fuction.

```
<a href="#" onclick="loginpw()" class="">Log In</a>

function loginpw(){
  alert("test");
}
```

I already tried with jquery, i don't get errors, but the code not work.

Error on framework7.js :

```js
    return function() {
    var t = arguments.length <= 0 ? void 0 : arguments[0];
    o && i || (r && t.stopPropagation(), n && t.preventDefault(), i = !0, e.apply(void 0, arguments))}
```

Comment: The code you've shown in the question doesn't appear to be the source of the error. If you double click the error in devtools it will take you to the line of code which caused the issue. There may also be a stack trace you can use to find the exact source too.

Comment: i added the source on my question

Comment: Thanks for that, however as it's an internal function within the framework7 library you'll need to check the stack trace to find out which part of your own code invoked it, to determine what the cause of the problem is